# Varbinary not working correcly in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, varbinarymax

I have this select query that gives the output "0x38F0A2D294A4AEBD1648C952D910AC51C40FE7"

```
SELECT HASHBYTES ('SHA1',CAST(54 AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar)
+CAST('2013-07-26 16:30:49.9786317' AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar))
```

Even knowing what SQL server does I'm not able to compare the column with the value. I'm doing this:

```
SELECT 'Worked!'
WHERE  HASHBYTES ('SHA1',CAST(54 AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar)+
CAST('2013-07-26 16:30:49.9786317' AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar))=0x38F0A2D294A4AEBD1648C952D910AC51C40FE7
```

This simply doesn't work. The strange part is that it works for other cases when the values are different.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [please don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @Hashthis nvarchar(2000)
SELECT @Hashthis=HASHBYTES ('SHA1',CAST(54 AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar)
+CAST('2013-07-26 16:30:49.9786317' AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar))

SELECT 'Worked' where HASHBYTES ('SHA1',CAST(54 AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar)
+CAST('2013-07-26 16:30:49.9786317' AS varchar)+CAST(1 AS varchar))=@Hashthis
```

Comment: it really work. But someone can tell me why it dosent work the other way? This way dosent have performance issues?